# Countdown timer on discount products pages

Tags: 7, entities, commerce, rules

I have created discounts on products, with an end date.

How do I display a countdown timer on my product pages (as in the screenshot) ?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Why is this question tagged with "Rules"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Field Timer](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_timer) module

> This module provides field which can be displayed as a
>   timer/**countdown**. A start/target date can be any date or an entity
>   property which represent a date (for example, created date of a node).
>   Module provides 4 field formatters: simple text and 3 formatters based
>   on jQuery plugins County and jQuery Countdown. If you are looking for
>   a configurable countdown/timer, this module is for you. It allows to
>   configure backgrounds, effects, formats, language of timer.

OR

[Countdown Timer Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_countdown)

> Countdown timer field module allows you to create countdown timer
>   field to count the days, hours, minutes, and seconds until a specified
>   event. The module uses jQuery Countdown Timer to display the countdown
>   timer in a nice graphical way.